# Spark Master to use multi core

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Im trying to run a simple pyspark word count program and would like to use multiple core in my machine, I have set the master to local[*] to use all the cores available but looks like its not using.

1. How will I know its using all cores?
2. Why I dont see any related print statement in the logs?

   ```
   import sys
   from operator import add

   from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


   if __name__ == '__main__':
   if len(sys.argv) != 2:
       print("Usage: wordcount <file>", file=sys.stderr)
       exit(-1)

   spark = SparkSession\
       .builder\
       .appName("PythonWordCount")\
       .master("local[*]")\
       .getOrCreate()

   lines = spark.read.text(sys.argv[1]).rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
   counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
                 .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
                 .reduceByKey(add)
   output = counts.collect()
   for (word, count) in output:
       print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

   spark.stop()
   ```

   ~

Comment: What's the size of file you are using ?

Comment: It's a very small file with one line.just want to test multi core

Comment: Use "top" to see the CPU usage of the Spark Java process. 
If the file is very small spark might keep it in a single partition. Can you check if the number of partitions is larger than 1 ( rdd.getNumPartitions() )?

Comment: Trying to test multicore processing with one single-line file certainly sounds like a bad idea...